# Javascript datepicker usage in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone correct my date picker code, I want to display only dates from 2013 to 2014 in from I tried like this, this works sometime but sometimes it shows 2004, 2024 also, please help me to correct and simplify code, and I want to create php function to display date range  in which I want to enter min and max like this `datepick('2013-01-01','2014-01-01')`

This is my code, with bug

HTML

```
<div id="date">

    <h1 id="dts"><br>SELECT DATE</h1>

    <label bottom="360px"> <b>From</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <br>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
    <br>
    <label> <b>To</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</br>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        maxDate: new Date('2014-12-31'),
        minDate: new Date('2013-01-01'),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        maxDate: new Date('2014-12-31'),
        minDate: +0,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E8HuW/)
[**jsFiddle/Results**](http://jsfiddle.net/E8HuW/embedded/result/)

In the fiddle `from` range is coming properly but in browser its showing 2024 also.

Comment: `minDate: new Date(2013, 1 - 1, 1),` and `maxDate: new Date(2014, 1 - 1, 1),`

Comment: `minDate : +0`? @MonkeyZeus: Not necessary. '2013-01-01' is a valid for these purposes.

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine for me by the way. Something wrong with your browser?

Comment: Guys please copy my code and run in your browser and refresh, it shows date which is other than the range I mentioned, I really have no idea about web programming/designing, I am learning...

Comment: If you close `To` without selecting a date, it clears `From` maxDate

Comment: @MarcB I agree, any reason the DOCs say `(new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26))`? http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: The only odd thing I can see is the `minDate` of the `#to` date picker. Also your `onClose` methods are both possibly clearing the other datepickers `minDate` or `maxDate` when no value is selected which looks suspect.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: shouldn't matter, since both methods would basically create the same object.

Comment: @MarcB I figured as much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inthe `onClose` function, check that a date was selected before using `selectedDate`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        maxDate: new Date('2014-12-31'),
        minDate: new Date('2013-01-01'),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            if (selectedDate) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        }
    });

    $("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        maxDate: new Date('2014-12-31'),
        minDate: +0,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            if (selectedDate) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/E8HuW/2/)

Another option would be to use `onSelect` instead of `onClose`, which is only triggered when the user selects a date.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/E8HuW/3/)

Comment: +1 accepted..Thanks, it works, but how can I create php function, I want embed it on html page I have many divisions returned by php functions/api.

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs. In the callback functions, `$(this)` is the datepicker element, you can use DOM traversal functions to find the corresponding from or to element.

Comment: I didn't get you please explain what is `$(this)` ?

Comment: It's the standard way in jQuery to access the target of an event.

Comment: By default, the year menu only goes back 10 years from the currently selected year. You can use an earlier minDate, but you may have to use multiple menu selections to get there (first select 2004, then look again and you'll see it). See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/E8HuW/5/. You can use the `yearRange` option to increase this.